# My Alfa AWUS036NH wireless card autorun installation disk will not run

Tags: wireless

I recently purchased an Alfa AWUS036NH wireless card. The installation is seamless on my windows machines, but the install CD will not run on my linux machines. The wireless card will show up as wlan1 (which is a good thing right?) on my linux machines alongside my wlan0, and I can use it with no problems... but the perplexing thing is i cant get the software to autorun and install. Normally I wouldn't care, but the Alfa Card has a nice GUI for managing available wireless networks, and it would be great to have that GUI on my linux machines like ALFA advertises. (i.e. 'WORKS WITH LINUX!')

Long story short, when I run the setup.exe, nothing happens, but I am able to view the files through the gui on my optical drive.

Could it be I need to 'sudo apt-get' something to autorun the software?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the card is already detected and running then the driver for the card is working properly.

Its a pity that that nice GUI tool that you have on the CD only works in Windows but most likely will be useless in Linux. Use the tools already provided in Ubuntu or look for one that works under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

the software is for windows (the disk is just windows drivers mainly, and mabye manual)
the linux support means, u can plug in, (and 9 out of 10 times it will just work)
if it says in  plain wording (just works) then its most likley it just will friend.

exe files can be run, usually they dont need to, in your case, it doesnt.
its only for programs, such as office, or games etc.

erm,  i would check to see if u can see a wireless icon up top,
click it, (do u see wireless networks?)   if yes, it is working

if  no, google the exact model say for example "Wireless-card-thingy on ubuntu"
change wireless-card-thingy to the name of your cards model

hope this helps

i found a link, it is slightly technical, but it seems to help users of your card/stick

http://www.leftech.com/getting_awus036nh_working_ubuntu_11_10.html

from supermorph